# API REST falcon python POST METHOD

Tags: python, api, post, falcon

I've tried to write an API REST using falcon.

on_get method works well, but when using on_post, I can't get the body of the POST request and I don't know why

```
class ProfileUpdate(object):
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        data = json.load(req.stream)
        print(data)
        resp.body = {"test": "answer"}
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        return resp


def setup_profile():
    app = falcon.API()

    profile_update = ProfileUpdate()
    app.add_route('/profiles', profile_update)

    return app
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 318, in __call__
    body, length = self._get_body(resp, env.get('wsgi.file_wrapper'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 820, in _get_body
    body = body.encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I am using Postman to test the API. I tried using the following body in POSTMAN (raw -> JSON)

```
{
"email":"test"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first, use `req.media` for retrieving data(suggestion).
second, for the response, use `resp.body = json.dumps({"test": "answer"})`

Comment: You don't need to call json.dumps explicitly. I've even defined a custom json encoder so I can just put whatever model in there, but by default it supports dicts, lists, simple types.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [documentation](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/media.html)

You can consume request raw body JSON by using `media` and also attach `media` to response.

> Zero configuration is needed if you’re creating a JSON API. Just
>   access or set the media attribute as appropriate and let Falcon do the
>   heavy lifting for you.

```
class EchoResource:
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        message = req.media.get("message")
        resp.media = {
            "message": message
        }
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

> Warning:
>
> Once media is called on a request, it’ll consume the request’s
>   stream.